# Classic ASP site only works if server is open via remote desktop

Tags: iis-7, asp

I have deployed the classic ASP website onto IIS 8 on a server. Now the classic ASP site only works if I have kept the server desktop open via remote desktop. If I close the remote desktop window and try to access the website, I get 500 Internal server error.

I have gone mad trying to resolve this issue from past few days.

Comment: Do you mean previously you were accessing the website locally via remote desktop (i.e., using the sever's browser), and now you're accessing it via a browser on another remote computer?

Comment: Actually the error was, I have deployed website on the server and accessing the same from my local machine. The website was accessible till I keep active RDP session with the server. As soon as RDP session is closed I would get 500 - Internal server error.

Comment: I have got the solution for the issue. The solution was with configuration of the COM+ component. The "Identity" of the component was set to "Interactive User - The Current logged on user". I changed it to "Network service" and the website is working properly even when RDP session is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please add your comments into the answer below, and check to accept it when you can, so that the question is considered closed. Thanks, and hope to see more questions from you in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution for the issue. The solution was with configuration of the COM+ component. The "Identity" of the component was set to "Interactive User - The Current logged on user". I changed it to "Network service" and the website is working properly even when RDP session is closed